# How to get Parent's variable in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

Could you help me with identifying child class. I'd like to get access to the Parent's variable in child class

```
class Parent:
   def __init__(self, p=None):
      self.p = p
      self.child = None

   def calc(self,):     
      self.child = Child('child')
  
class Child(Parent):
   def __init__(self, c=None):
      self.c = c
      self.print()

    def print(self,):
       print(self.c+Parent.p) 


p = Parent('parent')
p.calc()
```

It throws exception: AttributeError: type object 'Parent' has no attribute 'p'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the constructor of the superclass to get access to it, as is you are overriding the `__init__` in method `Child` so `Parent`'s one won't get called.

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, c=None):
        super().__init__()   # pass any arguments to parent __init__ here
        self.c = c
        self.print()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did a small error in code, the Parent class has self.p variable. So I might be missing theory totaly, but what I want to do is just to skip createing another identical variable self.p in the Child class, just use it's value in the child class. With super().__init__('test'), I won't get 'childparent' in the end. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Ok so `Parent.p` in your definition is a class variable, not an instance variable. You have to define it at the class level, not in `__init__`. Or you can do `print(self.c+Parent().p)`, but then it will be None and probably not what you want.